# How to Show Progressbar when video is loading after play some time (play from url) using ExoPlayer?

Tags: exoplayer

i am use Exoplayer for play video from Url But when video is Buffer during play at that time just Suck Player and nothing happen. so, i decide to show progress bar when video buffer during playing state.
so, how to achieve that using Exoplayer ?

Answer (score 2):

In Layout File

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/exo_player_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

In Activity Class implement `ExoPlayer.EventListener` and add this

```
@Override
public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

}

@Override
public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

}

@Override
public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

}

@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING){
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

}

@Override
public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

}

@Override
public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

}

@Override
public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

}

@Override
public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

}

@Override
public void onSeekProcessed() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement on your player activity

> ExoPlayer.EventListener

```
@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
   if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING) {
       //show your progress dialog here
    }
}
```